# Mac OS X Binary Repositories

Tags: macos, packaging

I know about a bunch of packaging system for Mac OS X plaftorm based on ports such as macports, fink, homebrew, pkgsrc and so on.

I was wandering if are there also binary repository for packages apt or rpm style for a quick and straightforward installation of big software with many dependencies.

Any suggestion? :D

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is [Rudix](http://rudix.org/documentation.html) If you only need some basic packages. All precompiled, and management simple with easy commands. I use it with macports with no problem, always giving preference to Rudix. A wonderful design!

If you want something precompiled and a greater number of packages, I recommend that you test the project pkgin [Save OS X](http://saveosx.org/a-warm-welcome/). 
I'll start a test on it today.

Hope this helps. 
Sorry for the english.

Comment: _"Save OS X"_ is no longer the name of the project, and indeed the old web site is now a German online dating site.  savemacos is really just a helper for using Joyent's pre-built pkgsrc builds.  See https://github.com/cmacrae/savemacos

Comment: Thanks for the info Greg!

Answer (score 0):

Fink supports binary packages but my experience some time ago was that they lagged quite a bit behind the source packages they had available. pkgsrc also supports binary packages but the [ones for Darwin](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/Darwin/i386/) don't appear to have been updated for Snow Leopard (Darwin 10). If you're happy building from source pkgsrc itself works well on OS X (I use it myself).

It appears that if someone were to to a bulk package build for Mac OS X in pkgsrc the repo could be used with [pkgin](http://imil.net/pkgin/) to get easy binary package management.

Comment: Joyent has been building pkgsrc for Darwin/OS X for some years now and they support `pkgin`: https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/install-on-osx/

Answer (score 0):

Joyent has been building pkgsrc for Darwin/OS X for some years now and they support `pkgin`: https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/install-on-osx/